# Lattice Energy and Stability in s block compounds

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

Lattice energy decreases down the group but stability of the compound still increases why?
For the purpose of this post I'll take alkali earth metal carbonate as an example.
As we go down the group size of cation increases and hence the lattice energy decreases, however my book stated that

> The thermal stability (of carbonates) increases with increasing cationic size

I've heard that big cations are able to form better stable compounds with big anions. However we say that lattice energy has decreased. Then what is the factor that is providing this stability in an ionic compound ?

Comment: In this case the smaller cation will polarize the lager cation and thus decrease stability.

Comment: So it is basically that the development of covalent character is the factor responsible for decreasing stability ? and so can I conclude that as we are going down although lattice energy is decreasing but ionic character is becoming greater which is making it more stable !??

Comment: Yes, that is right.